# CRA Webpack Dependency Optimization

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

Does Create-React-App (or Webpack used by Create-React-App) at any stage (development, staging or production) optimise your node_modules? That is, if I had an import like this:

`import _ from 'lodash'`

and only use the `map` function in my project. Would my build bundle for production have all of lodash or would it strip out all other functions and keep the ones that are being referenced in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRA use `UglifyJsPlugin` in the [webpack.config.prod.js](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/c6375edc079a71bd9addd50c58441cbca8839945/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js#L293) which supports dead code removal.

But you should only import what you need for this to work: https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: So if I import all of lodash then my bundle would not be optimized to only have what I need? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, and for loadash you might even need [babel-plugin-lodash](https://github.com/lodash/babel-plugin-lodash/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbled here in 2021, create-react-app also do tree-shaking when you use `import * as _  from 'lodash`